# How to generate JSON for dynamic data

Tags: c#, json

I have a set of data(key value pair) which I need map to json, 
note keys are not fixed, name of keys are not fixed. thanks 
e.g.

How to map

```
dict<string, list<string>>
    {"Module",new List<String>(){"Allprice"}},  
        {"Code",new List<String>(){"PA0000606", "PA0000669"}},  
     {"ContinuosForwardPeriod", new List<string>() {"0"} ,
     { "TimeStampID", new List<string>{"0"},
    {"PriceTypeID": "8"}
```

to

```
[
 { "Module": "Allprice", 
   "Code": "PA0000606", 
   "ContinuosForwardPeriod": "0", 
   "TimeStampID": "0", 
   "PriceTypeID": "8" 
 },
 { "Module": "Allprice", 
   "Code": "PA0000669", 
   "ContinuosForwardPeriod": "0", 
   "TimeStampID": "0", 
   "PriceTypeID": "8" 
 }
]
```

Comment: minor nitpick: the proper spelling is "continuous" (note second u).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer;    
JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string JSON = oSerializer.Serialize(yourDict);
```